# Add a parallel node in TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms

This may be very easy question but I am thinking of solution for a long while. I need to keep some condition in the `if` statement stating that the node is the parent node of all in the TreeView control. Please suggest what expression should I keep in the `if` statement.

```
if(Condition??)          //it is the parent node of all
{
   myTreeView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(myTreeNode);
}
else
{
   myTreeView.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.Add(myTreeNode);
}
```

In the above code I am trying to add a parallel node to the selected node which is working but when I am trying the same code (i.e., `myTreeView.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.Add(myTreeNode);`)  to parent node, VS was showing error.(which I know why so I am trying the above code to achieve it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`TreeNode.Parent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.parent.aspx) property for this:

```
if (myTreeView.SelectedNode.Parent == null && myTreeView.SelectedNode.Parent.GetType() != typeof(TreeNode))
{
   myTreeView.SelectedNode.Nodes.Add(myTreeNode);
}
else
{
   myTreeView.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.Add(myTreeNode);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response.. this is not working. Giving error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." at the if statement.

Comment: Hey its working.. I was trying `if (tvEditor.SelectedNode.Parent.Equals(null))` I thought It is same as `if (tvEditor.SelectedNode.Parent == null )`. aren't they same?

Comment: 1.    == is swallo comparison. Means it will use the memory location for comparison rather that the data.

2. .equals() is indepth comparison. I will check the content between two object rather that the memory location.